# Spring Batch StoredProcedureItemReader to read StoredProc with only output parameters(no input Params)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have SP with only 4 output params and no input params, and my StoredProcedureItemReader conf look like this

```
<bean id="spItemReader">
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="procedureName" value="mynamespace.spname"/>
    <property name="refCursorPosition" value="1"></property>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="MyRowMapper"/>
    </property>
    <property name="parameters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="column1"/>
                <constructor-arg index="1">
                    <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.SMALLINT"/>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="P_column2"/>
                <constructor-arg index="1">
                    <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR"/>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="P_column3"/>
                <constructor-arg index="1">
                    <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.INTEGER"/>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="P_column4"/>
                <constructor-arg index="1">
                    <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.CHAR"/>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have the dataSource as instance of `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` and connecting to `DB2` with `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver` as driver class.

And my Job configuration is as below:

```
<job id="testJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="spItemReader" writer="eventItemWriter"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>
```

I have writer as `StaxEventItemWriter` and proper `unmarshaller` configuration.

The Problem is When i run the Batch, I keep getting :

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Executing stored procedure; bad SQL grammar [{call mynamespace.spname(?, ?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=PROCEDURE;BSCPROC.PKA109, DRIVER=4.19.26

I'm not sure what i'm missing, please advice how should i fix this.
Let me also know if any more information is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I myself have found a resolution. The Spring Batch API provided **StoredProcedureItemReader** provides **PreparedStatementSetter**, which has to be typecast to **CallableStatement**. Because StoredProcedures will not work with PreparedStatements. We will have to override the setValues methods by providing custom implementation for PreparedStatementSetter. And here is how the config should look.

Note: property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="paramSet"

Code:

```
<bean id="spItemReader"
 class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader" >
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="procedureName" value="mynamespace.spname"/>
<property name="refCursorPosition" value="1"></property>
 <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="paramSet" ></property>  
<property name="rowMapper">
    <bean class="MyRowMapper"/>
</property>
<property name="parameters">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="column1"/>
            <constructor-arg index="1">
                <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.SMALLINT"/>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="P_column2"/>
            <constructor-arg index="1">
                <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR"/>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="P_column3"/>
            <constructor-arg index="1">
                <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.INTEGER"/>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="P_column4"/>
            <constructor-arg index="1">
                <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.CHAR"/>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="paramSet" class="com.jpmc.ib.asup.batch.CustomSPParamSetter" ></bean>
```

PreparedStatementSetter Implementation:

Code:

```
public class CustomSPParamSetter implements PreparedStatementSetter{

@Override
public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {

    CallableStatement eventCallableSt=(CallableStatement)ps;
    eventCallableSt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.SMALLINT);
    eventCallableSt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    eventCallableSt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    eventCallableSt.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
}
}
```

Its not logical to declare to SP parameters in both spring config file and the PreparedStatementSetter. But this is the correct working solution for me.

Comment: Can I ask how do you get values of out Parameters in RowMapper? I noticed you have used <property name="refCursorPosition" value="1"></property>

Comment: Please share full code if have.. How to pass current date as parameter in stored procedure by using this..